# Plex and Folding at Home

Tags: automation, plex, foldingathome

I had Plex and F@H on my old Win7 server but am going to be upgrading and hoping to switch to a Linux environment (Ubuntu). On my old Win system, I used a program called Automate6 to do macro stuff. When someone started watching something on Plex and the Plex transcoding service started, Automate would click on the pause button on the F@H Control panel giving Plex all the processing power. Then when Plex was done with the transcoding service, Automate would click the play button on the F@H Control panel.
Are their any macro type programs for the Ubuntu environment or can this be done in services???
I am new to the Linux world, have been playing with it for almost a month now so I do have some of the basics down.

Comment: I don't suggest an automation program here. Instead, you can give one process more priority. For example, I can give Plex the default priority, and F@H a lower priority. This would mean that when the CPU isn't too busy, F@H can run, but when Plex wants CPU, it gets priority. Check out [the `nice` command](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man1/nice.1.html). Warning: If you give something a super high priority, it may cause problems, especially if it is a higher priority than, say, the keyboard. So don't max out the priority of something. Would something like that work for you?

Comment: Sounds good, will this also apply to the transcode GPU power?